# How to pass some utterance identifier to speak() in TTS library of React-native to control the actions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text-to-speech

How to pass some utterance identifier to speak() in TTS library of React-native to control the actions later. I want to get it back using callback to perform actions further once tts-finish event occured. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Modified react-native-tts speak() function to support utterance id.